# Why do we use $cm^2$?

Tags: geometry, education, area

I can't seem to wrap my head around why we should use $cm^2$ for area.
According to my textbook we use it for converting units of area but I don't understand how $1cm$ is any different from $1cm^2$.

Can someone please explain why I should change the unit from $cm$ to $cm^2$ when working with area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use cm when we want to measure the length of a one dimensional object. Cm can be used when finding perimeter, or when finding the length of a line.

cm$^2$ is used when we want to find the specific area of something. Why cm$^2$? Let's say we want to find the area of a rectangle that is $8$cm long and $7$cm wide. Normally you would just do $8\times 7=56$ and attach the cm$^2$ to the end of it. But let's do this properly, using the actual units in our calculation.
$$A=8\text{cm}\times 7\text{cm}=56\times \text{cm}\times \text{cm}=56\text{cm}^2$$
Why can't you use cm when finding area? Remember, cm is to find *length*. How would you find the length of the inside of this square?
$$\square$$
You can try to draw lines in the square to find the length. But lines have no area$^*$ (which is why you can't use cm$^2$ for measuring length) so you could draw one billion lines and still be stuck in the first half. You will never be able to fill up that square using lines! So you cannot use cm for area$^{**}$.

$^*$ Technically the area of a line is $0$cm$^2$. Say you want to find the area of a line $8$cm long. This line has $0$cm width, so the area would be $8$cm $\times$ $0$cm $=$ $0$cm$^2$

$^{**}$ You can say that the length of the inside of a square is $\infty$ cm (it does not matter what unit you use actually).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Now I see why we use $cm^2$.

Answer (score 3):

This has 1 point

$$ \cdot $$

This has a length of 0 cm:

$$ \cdot $$

This has an area of 0 cm${}^2$:

$$ \cdot $$

This has $\infty$ points

$$ - $$

This has a length of approximately one cm:

$$ - $$

This has an area of zero cm${}^2$:

$$ -  $$

This has $\infty$ points

$$ \blacksquare $$

This has a length of $\infty$ cm:

$$ \blacksquare $$

This has an area of approximately one cm${}^2$:

$$ \blacksquare $$

Comment: @JChau: A square is made up of infinitely many lines of length 1 cm, so when you add up to get the total lengths, you get $\infty$! When working, e.g., in the plane, there are a number of measures you can use. The point counting measure, the length measure, the area measure, measures that weight different parts of the plane differently, more exotic measures.... The point is, these measures apply to *any* measurable set. And any set that has positive area necessarily has infinite length.

Comment: @JChau: ... when we say we're measuring the perimeter of $\blacksquare$, we're not measuring the length of $\blacksquare$: we're measuring the length of $\square$. Similarly, when we talk about the "length and width" of $\blacksquare$, with their usual English usage, we are not actually measuring $\blacksquare$, but instead are measuring $\underline{\ \ \ }$, $\overline{\ \ \ }$, $|$, and $|$. If we try to make sense of actually asking for the length of $\blacksquare$, we are led to it having to be $\infty$, by the argument I made at the beginning of my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

They measure different things: $\mathrm{cm}$ is a measure of length, and $\mathrm{cm}^2$ is a measure of area (and $\mathrm{cm}^3$ is a measure of volume).

If a rectangle has side lengths $a\, \mathrm{cm}$ and $b\, \mathrm{cm}$ then the area of the rectangle is $(a \times b)\, \mathrm{cm}^2$.

Likewise, if a cuboid side lengths $a\, \mathrm{cm}$, $b\, \mathrm{cm}$ and $c\, \mathrm{cm}$ then the volume of the cuboid is $(a \times b \times c)\, \mathrm{cm}^3$.

Comment: Why is that we have to change from $1cm = 10mm$ to $1cm^2 = 100mm^2$?

Comment: $1\,cm^2=(10\,mm)^2=10^2\,mm^2=100\,mm^2$.

Comment: @C1D:  Cut a $1\ cm$ square into $1 \ mm$ squares.  How many do you get?  Each side gets cut $10$ times.  There are $100$ small squares.

Comment: Take a $1$cm by $1$cm square. The area is $1$cm$^2$, right? Remember, the square is also the same as a $10$mm by $10$mm square (remember, $10$mm=$1$cm). The area of this square is $100$mm$^2$. The area of both squares are the same. Therefore $1$cm$^2=100$mm$^2$.